# How to crawl all pages with Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape all the link to the formation of this site : https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/

So first of all, ilauched this script just to test and see if I could scrape the link for the first page :

```
import scrapy


class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    #allow_domains = ['https://www.formatic-centre.fr/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/']

    #rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'formation'), callback="parse", follow= True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//a[@class="title"]')
        for a in card:
            yield {'links': a.xpath('@href').get()}
```

It worked, I obtained this :

```
[
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/les-regles-juridiques-du-teletravail/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/mieux-gerer-son-stress-en-periode-du-covid-19/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/dynamiser-vos-equipes-special-post-confinement/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/conduire-ses-entretiens-specifique-post-confinement/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/cours-excel/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/autocad-3d-2/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/concevoir-et-developper-une-strategie-marketing/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/preparer-soutenance/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/mettre-en-place-une-campagne-adwords/"},
{"links": "https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/utiliser-google-analytics/"}
]
```

But when I want to crawl all the pages, things get dirty.. and I get lost, my script doesn't work anymore, I guess my loop isn't quite right because I have doublon and so on.

Here's my final script :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    #allow_domains = ['https://www.formatic-centre.fr/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/']

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'formation'), callback="parse", follow= True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//a[@class="title"]')
        for a in card:
            yield {'links': a.xpath('@href').get()}



        next_page = response.xpath('.//a[@class="pagination__next btn-squae"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                response.urljoin(next_page),
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

Maybe it's my path ? I check and double check to see where the "next button" was to put the good href and I put : `.//a[@class="pagination__next btn-squae"]/@href`

But weirdly enough, the link in the html source doesn't link to the 2nd page, so I'm confused.

Here -> [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdPQW.png)

Any ideas ?

EDIT : Apparently I need some `FormRequest`, is it this kind of code I need to use ? [ajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9yCU.png)

Comment: Do you want to collect all internal links or something specific?

Comment: Something specific. Not all the link, the link who refer to the formation. Like in the example above. (first image)

Comment: Pardon? Links for every page?

Comment: No no, links for every formation like this one : https://www.formatic-centre.fr/formation/les-regles-juridiques-du-teletravail/ for all the kinf for all the pages

Answer (score 1):

The next pages are dynamically loaded with AJAX. You will have to simulate those requests using `FormRequest` from scrapy.

I suggest you read [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html?highlight=dynamically).

To summarize, you will have to use the browser’s Developer Tools to observe the how (and where to) the request is made, copy the form (sometimes the headers are required as well) and yield a `FormRequest`.

### Edit:

- Open the page
- Open the browser developer tools (Or inspect some element)
- Click the network tab. Filter by "XHR".
- Then click the next button on the page
- You should see a new request appear like in the image:
  [image]

Select the request. The side data is details of this request.

The rectangle is showing the destination of the request the browser made.
Lower there is a field "Response Headers" (visible), under that (you can't see in the image) there will be a request headers, these are the parameters your browser used as headers for the request.
There is a tab named "Request", there you will find the formdata your browser used for the POST request.

You will have to make use of the FormRequest and simulate the request your browser made. Start by copying the parameters in the form, if it doesn't work include the headers in the request.

**This is Firefox by the way. Other browsers may have different locations for  the options I mentioned.**

The idea here is that Scrapy should simulate the browser's behavior. Most of the time this is a painless process (once you understand what you are doing), but sometimes it can be quite painful and take a good amount of time, so take it easy.

Comment: Ok I will check it out.

Comment: I'm lost, I can't figure out where the request is made, I found something but I'm not even sure that's that.

Comment: @LaurieFalcon I edited my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your detailled answer but I cant' figure it out why I'm suppose to do with formdata, it's just params. Maybe I'm not in the right place.

Comment: When you click the next button, it makes a POST request to the server. POST requests carry a message in it's body that's made out of a form. Those fields you are seeing are the message sent in your request and therefore you will have to include that data in your Scrapy request. For that you'll need to use `FormRequest` which is a method of Scrapy. [Details here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects). It seems you are missing some key concepts here, so you will have to take some time to read on the links I posted and search what you dont understand.

Comment: I understand how to get there, what I'm not it's how to put this kind of data into scrapy. What you call parameters is this kind of things : params[0][atts][layout] "course"?

Comment: I tried to put parameters and headers but it didn't work. I guess I'm doing something wrong.